# Get shapes on screen

Tags: processing, shapes

I have created a grid of thumbs. When a certain thumb is pressed I want the image that is linked to the thumb added on screen. I know i'm supposed to write the loadImages in setup(), but i'm a bit confused on how to do this.

```java
PShape[] Quotes = new PShape[6];
int qLength = Quotes.length;

setup() {
    size(1024, 768);
}

draw() {
    stroke(bruin);
    strokeWeight(5);
    fill(wit);

    rectMode(CORNER);
    rect(guide, 280, bBorder, 145);

    noStroke();
    fill(bruin);
    rect(guide, 280, bBorder, 40);

    textFont(kaffeesatzFont);
    textSize(30);
    fill(wit);
    text("Quotes", 80, 308);

    createGridQ();

}

void createGridQ(){

    xOffset = 30;
    yOffset = 325;
    xSize = 50;
    ySize = 38;
    padding = 10;
    xPos = padding + xOffset;
    yPos = yOffset;
    cols = 3;

    for(int j = 0; j < qLength; j++){
        // Grid
        xPos = xOffset + ((j % cols) * (xSize+padding));
        yPos = yOffset + ((j / cols) * (ySize+padding));

        Quotes[j] = loadShape("Q" + j + ".svg");
        shape(Quotes[j], xPos, yPos);


        if((mouseX >= xPos) && (mouseX <= xPos+xSize) && 
           (mouseY >= yPos) && (mouseY <= yPos+ySize)){ 

            cursor(HAND);

            if (mousePressed){
                cursor(HAND);

                Quotes[j] = loadShape("Q" + j + "groot" + ".svg");
                shape(Quotes[j], width/5, height/2-200); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image by declaring a PImage and loading it from a web url or by placing it into your data or source directory (where your .pde files are) and then loading it from there.

```
PImage img;
img = loadImage("laDefense.jpg");
```

[Processing loadImage Reference](http://www.processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html)

So, replace "laDefense.jpg" with the name of the image you want to use and place that image into your data folder. After that, you can place the image in the scene and manipulate it as you would a shape.

Comment: I'm aware of this. The problem is when i click on the thumb that is connected to the shape it only appears when the mouse is clicked (mousePressed), obviously, I want it to be added on the screen when it's clicked on.

Comment: If you know all of the images that will be used beforehand, then load them in setup into a data structure of your choosing. Store another data structure of objects with image index and location. As a thumb is clicked, store the click location and the index of the image to the written and on every draw loop, iterate through the list drawing all objects.